# org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "Some URL": Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Tags: java, apigee, sslhandshakeexception, pcf, spring-framework-beans

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "Some URL": Received fatal alert: bad_certificate;nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Users Register through Apigee.
Uses b2b and Mobile Token.
Seeing this error in PCF logs.

Can anyone give any insights?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you can post your code and context around what you're trying to achieve it will better help us help you.

Comment: The Spring Boot Application runs on PCF. EndUser from a Mobile App uses the Web Services written in the my Application. Mobile App hits Apigee, from there the requests come. Now, for any new user registration I'm getting this error in the log.

Comment: User Registration checks also if the user exists or not. It has a different Api call...which resides in a different server.